# Solving Assembly not Found | FileNotFoundException | Fusion Log

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, fusion

I am trying to deploy my solution package (wsp) to SharePoint 2007 environment. The WSP contains a feature which loads the feature receiver class to deploy a timer job at run time.

While deploying this WSP, I am consistently getting

> Feature
>   'fb631f6c-2c46-4ab5-b7b3-f3d0c949c5f0'
>   could not be installed because the
>   loading of event receiver assembly
>   "XXX, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=bad6857072694970"
>   failed:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException

I have double checked everything (public key token, assembly name etc) is correct. I have deployed many WSP in past and I am confused why this one is failing.

To debug this , I am using Assembly Binding Log Viewer. I have selected "Log in exception text" and given custom log path. Neither I am getting any log messages and the exception text is consistently giving this message:

> WRN: Assembly binding logging is
>   turned OFF.  To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry
>   value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]
>   (DWORD) to 1.  Note: There is some
>   performance penalty associated with
>   assembly bind failure logging.  To
>   turn this feature off, remove the
>   registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Any ideas why this could be happening ? How to enable Assembly Binding Log viewing?

Comment: `To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1`

Comment: Did it manually and I guess the tool (Assembly Binding Log Viewer) does it too, still the same message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn the logging on use **Regedit** and updated the registry entry in the error message.

It could be that your program requires a dll that is not included in the package.

Sometimes it just needs an IISRESET to realise that the dll is available in the GAC.

Comment: Did it manually and I guess the tool (Assembly Binding Log Viewer) does it too, still the same message

Comment: Try an IISRESET, if that does not work try restarting the machine. I run with this setting on, but cannot remember if I needed to restart to get it to work.

Comment: Another cause I've found is trying to use a "Debug" build of a .dll on a machine with only the Redistributable package (CRT100 specifically) installed.