# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.RFCOMAPILib in IIS 7.5 while trying to load my web service

Tags: vb.net

Win 2008 R2 X64 bit 
IIS 7.5

I am trying to run by web service and trying to connect to the Rightfax client and see the below error and the right fax client is installed and i see the rfcomapi.dll in there but it is unable to access the rfcomapilib. file .

did any one go through this?

Error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Interop.RFCOMAPILib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.

Comment: You might try what solved this guy's problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878602/system-io-filenotfoundexception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-x-or-one-of-i

Comment: That's the interop library, you got it when you added the reference to Rightfax.  Did you forget to copy it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late, but do the following to fix issue:

1. Make sure the project can find the dll file
   Next...
2. Navigate to C:\Windows\assembly
3. drop your dll file in the above directory
4. you're all set.

Along with making sure the project can find your dll file, it must also be registered in the assembly directory