# WP8 Project: The "CompileXaml" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I've reinstalled Windows on my computer, and after I open any Windows Phone 8 project in Visual Studio 2012 for Windows Phone, I get the following error message:

```
The "CompileXaml" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'XamlServicesWP, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the specified file.
File name: 'XamlServicesWP, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.CompileXaml.GenerateCode(ITaskItem item, Boolean isApplication)
   at Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.CompileXaml.Execute()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext()

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
    MyProject
```

I tried to reinstall Visual Studio twice, but it didn't solve it..

How can I solve this?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878602/system-io-filenotfoundexception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-x-or-one-of-i)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Install [Visual Studio 2012 Update 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305), and then latest [update for the Phone SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41559).

[Origin.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/5f073bf5-4b8c-4fd3-8b83-5dd02a03e07a/sdk-80-systemiofilenotfoundexception-xamlserviceswp?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: Reinstalling the Update 4 was what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

For those, who has this problem in Visual Studio 2013 - try to install Visual Studio 2013 Update 4. Seems that there are some problems with MSBuild sometimes, reinstall helps.