# The “CompileXaml” task failed unexpectedly when building for specific platforms

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

To use SQLite in Windows Phone 8 app, I need to build for specific platforms - x86 or ARM, depending on where the package will be used (emulator or device, respectively)

However, as soon as I switch from building from Any CPU to ARM/x86, I get wild error(s) in Visual Studio.

> Error 15  The "CompileXaml" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file
>   '...SomePageName.g.cs' because it is being used by another process.

Things I've tried and other relevant info:

- I have only one Visual Studio instance running
- Blend is closed
- I don't have any specific SQLite related changes, just project/solution configuration changes
- I have installed Visual Studio Update 4
- I have tried restarting Visual Studio
- I have tried cleaning the solution/projects
- I have tried deleting the .suo file
- I have reinstalled the emulators update mentioned [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995605/wp8-project-the-compilexaml-task-failed-unexpectedly)
- I have tried building with msbuild outside of Visual Studio (and it works, but I want to build from Visual Studio)

`msbuild "myProjectNameAndPath.csproj" /t:Rebuild /p:Platform=x86 /p:Configuration=Release`

Any other reasonable explanation why Visual Studio 2013 is failing with these errors?

> Error 14  The process cannot access the file '...SomePage.g.cs' because
>   it is being used by another process.