# CompileXaml error when compiling xamarin on visual studio

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, xamarin.forms

I have a PCL solution with specific projects for Androis, iOS and Windows Phone.

Everything is going fine for Android and iOS but when I try to compile winPhone through Visual Studio I receive the following message:

```
    The "CompileXaml" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'XamlServicesWP, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.
File name: 'XamlServicesWP, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.CompileXaml.GenerateCode(ITaskItem item, Boolean isApplication)
   at Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.CompileXaml.Execute()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext()

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
    Overactive.Pronto.WinPhone
```

Does anyone have any idea on what am I skipping here?

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995605/wp8-project-the-compilexaml-task-failed-unexpectedly

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, I already have the Update 5 installed but I'm still getting the same error. Unfortunately I cannot comment on that thread cause I'm a newbie here

Comment: did you install an update recently?