# FileNotFoundException WpfAnimatedGif

Tags: c#, wpf, gif, filenotfoundexception, wpf-animation

I'm trying to get a gif in a WPF window.
Within the designer its loaded, it's even animated.

But whenever I build and start the application

***FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'WpfAnimatedGif, PublicKeyToken=9e7cd3b544a090dc' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.***

It's a Packaged I downloaded, the reference is set to copy local = true.
I also tried false but it didn't work. Tried rebuilding it and building it on other x64 and 'any CPU

Can't seem to figure it out. Any help is welcome

Comment: Use tips in posts with similar error (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10878602/1997232) is one) to find out what is missing.

Comment: Is there a `WpfAnimatedGif.dll` in the output folder at runtime?

Comment: Yes there is. Naming also checked out.

Comment: That post didn't solve it. The dependencywalker is for windows 2003 so doesn't work. Rest of them did not help. I'm quite lost with dependencies etc

Comment: I tested the NuGet package on a sample project and it worked fine. Did you install the NuGet package, or did you set the reference some other way? Also, have you tried closing and restarting Visual Studio?

Comment: I downloaded it from nuget package. And i also tries restarting visual studio.