# Could not load file or assembly of project resource file

Tags: .net, winforms

i am currently trying to run my Application. For whatever reason I am gettings the following error:

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly '[PROJECTNAME].resources, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=de-DE, PublicKeyToken=null'.`

I cant find such file in the build folder. However it worked before but i didnt change anything(checked with source control). Is there anything I can do to add this file?
I thought of changing the culture of the resource file since it says its german but I dont know how to do that.
If someone can help but needs a specific part of code im happy to provide it. Thanks in advance

Delete:
.vs
bin
obj

Tried to clean the project and tried to reclone it. => Didnt work

Comment: There's a similar question asked before - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878602/system-io-filenotfoundexception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-x-or-one-of-i. Give it a try first.

Comment: Already tried that. Didnt work